I'm facing this error due to update user image possible unhandled promise rejection (id 3) typeerror network request failed
I'm using React  native expo with fire-store and I'm trying to update and upload user image so when I open the album to select a photo then press update button I get this error
Here is the Code
 {/*fetch user data from firestore like name */}

    React.useEffect (()=>{
      const getUserData = async () => {
        const auth = getAuth(app);

        const docRef = doc(db,'users', auth?.currentUser?.uid)
        const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef)
        if (docSnap.exists()) {
          console.log("Document data:", docSnap.data());
          setUserData(docSnap.data());
        } else {
          // docSnap.data() will be undefined in this case
          console.log("No such document!");
        }

 {/*update user profile photo*/}
    async function uploadImage (uri, fileType) {

      const response = await fetch(uri)
      const blob = await response.blob()

      const sotrageRef = ref(storage, 'image/' + new Date().getTime())
      const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(sotrageRef, blob)
    

      //
      uploadTask.on("state_change",
        (snapshot)=> {
          const progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100

          console.log("progress", progress)
        },
        (error) => {
          //handle error
        },
        () => {
          getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then(async(getDownloadURL)=>{
           console.log("File available at", getDownloadURL)
           
            // save record
            await saveRecord(fileType, getDownloadURL, new Date().toISOString())
           setImage()
          })
        }
      )
    }

 {/* function to save the file */}

 const saveRecord = async (fileType,url, createAt) => {
    const auth = getAuth(app)
    const docRef = doc(db, "users", auth?.currentUser.uid,)
    try {
     // const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, 'users'),{
      await updateDoc(docRef,{
        fileType,
        url,
        createAt,
      });
      console.log('document saved correctly', docRef.id)
      
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
      
    }


So please anyone knows which part or line in code cause problem and knows how to solve it please do  help me out  as I have spent hours on fixing this but I couldn't. your help is extremely considered.
